# Why does orientationchange event doesn't fire on desktop?

Tags: javascript, html

I know there is no such concept of "orientation change" on desktops, but inside chrome dev tools there is an option to change the orientation. I see "resize" event firing on changing the orientation which is justified.. since AxB becomes BxA, but why doesn't the orientation even fires?

**What alternative can I use to make sure I can fire an event whenever orientation changes on ANY device ?**

index.html:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="./main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function(){
    this.console.log("orientation changed")
});
window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
    this.console.log("resized")
});
```

I even tried the jquery event handler, doesn't work.

on chrome 79 for mac.
Thankyou.

Comment: Orientation change can arguably have some meaning on a desktop if one changes the OS settings to change the monitor display from landscape to portrait or vice versa, but it doesn't look to trigger `orientationchange` either

Comment: Yes makes sense, please let me know if you come across a solution.

Comment: you mean you are triggering it form the "responsive design mode" or whatever it's called on chrome? It does fire for me on v79

Comment: @Kaiido select "Responsive" as device and not any other tablet / phone in "responsive design mode" editor in chrome dev tools. you'll notice orientation even fires when the device is any phone/tablet, but when you choose device as "Responsive", it doesn't fire the event.

Comment: For me even in "Responsive" mode, the event is fired.

Comment: @Kaiido then I guess there are other things playing a role as well which we are not aware of... but the method suggested below by Kaiido seems great. I have seen many people explaining issues they face with jaavscript events.

Comment: Damn, I for a second thought the comment to which I replied to was from CertainPerformance haha. I just referred you to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`orientationchange` is the correct event to listen to if you are interested in orientation changes.

What you are describing should work from your dev-tools, since these will extend the available web-API to make your desktop browser behave like a mobile one, from where orientation can really change.
From my Chrome 79 on macOs, clicking the responsive's mode "rotate" icon makes the event fire just fine.

[image: screenshot of the page in responsive mode with the console output showing an orientationchange event has fired]

---

Now, if you wish to check when even a desktop browser passes in vertical mode or horizontal mode, you still have the option to add [MediaQuery](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia):

```js
const query = matchMedia("screen and (orientation:portrait)");

query.onchange = e => {
  console.log( 'orientation change', query.matches ? 'portrait' : 'landscape' );
  // though beware square will be marked as landscape here,
  // if you want to handle this special case
  // create an other mediaquery (orientation:landscape) 
}
```

```html
You may have to run this snippet in "full page" mode
```

Comment: this matchMedia is exactly what I was looking for, Thanks! I want whatever device that I have, whenever it's orientation changes, I want an event fired.